# How can I control Django-admin panel permissions across two apps?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two apps "App1" & "App2". Using "App2" views.py I want to display the information about models of "App1" but with only read-only permissions. like just display the info in the same manner Django-admin does.

Comment: try django permissions I hope that you find something good in docs

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). Here a simple example:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.utils import timezone

from you_app.models import App2

class App2ListView(ListView):
    model = App2
```

The above will generate an `object_list`, so in your template you can parse it and print it.